# In the late 18th century, would any of the southwestern area of Germany used Franks instead of their own currency?

Tags: germany, 18th-century, currency

While looking up family history I found an old German marriage document which specified a dowry of "1000 Franks." With that, the families in question were from the Suggental/Waldkirch area in what is today the German State of Baden-Württemberg in the northern parts of the "Black Forest." The two possibilities I can think of is that either they used Swiss or French Franks or Francs because they may have moved from either area, or there might have potentially been some sort of Swiss or French influence in the area. The latter, to me, does not seem as possible.

Comment: You might get a reasonable answer if you tell us the date of the document.

Comment: @fdb: Actually, I fail to see how any specific date between 1500 and 1806 would enlighten us more than *late 18th century* already does.

Comment: @fdb... 1788 was the year of the agreement.

Comment: In the late 18s century, there was no "Germany".

Comment: @Alex I am well aware of that. People still identified themselves as Germans. The agreement was written in High German.

Comment: The French Franc a decimal currency was introduced in 1795, the Swiss 1850. Before that a specific silver coin was called Franc. This silver coin will most probely be what is meant. (Good that we have an exact date)

Answer (score 7):

Note that [for the time period of interest there was no single *German* state](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4c/HRR_1789_EN.png), as we are talking not only long before the German unification of the mid Nineteenth Century but also well before the simplification of German states that occurred during the Napoleonic period. [Consequently:](http://coinquest.com/cgi-bin/cq/coins?main_coin=5074)

> Up to that time [1871] several dozen independent German States and cities
>   issued their own coinage under their own rulers.

Other common possible choices might have been either the [Prussian Thaler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prussian_thaler) or the [Bavarian Gulden](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bavarian_gulden). The marriage contract was likely denominated in the currency that was kept in hand by the bride's father, as in that way currency exchange would be minimized. If the bride's father was selling property in order to raise the dowry amount, he would have negotiated a currency choice matching that of the expected sale, again to minimize currency exchange.

Comment: Thank you for the comment; it has been very helpful. In another marriage contract in 1813, in the same area, Guldens were the currency used.

Comment: @oswana21: I note that a religious man might still have a lingering affection in this time period for *Catholic* currencies such as the Gulden or French Frank over a *Protestant* one like the Swiss Frank or Prussian Thaler.

Comment: It was definitely a Catholic wedding.

Comment: I would like to note that at the time, money was *bullion*; in other words a French (or other) coin was supposed to have a silver or gold weight equal to its face value. As long it was a currency known enough that everybody around you knew its value (relative to other local currencies or goods), the country of origin was not as important (unless it was known that it debased the currency). What you got was not as much X livres or marks, but Y grams of gold (or silver) certified by the French (or Prussian or Bavarian) mint.

Answer (score 1):

This refers to the French pound, the *livre*. French money was in common use in Germany, Italy and many other places during the 1700s. The livre was worth about $12 - $25. There were 24 silver livres in a Louis, which was the gold coin.

Comment: Where did you get your information from so I can continue research?

Comment: This is common knowledge. You could just read the Wikipedia articles on the French monetary system. If you read contemporary French and German novels from the period in question you will find references to the common sorts of money. For example *Histoire de Ma Vie* by Casanova and the autobiography of Karl Philipp Moritz.

Comment: Franc d'argent was a silver coin that was minted. The name was later (1795) used to name the decimal currency that replaced the livre.